# Парсер для всех листов excel python

Tags: python, xlrd

Написал парсер для эксель на питоне. Использую библиотеку xlrd. Проблема заключается в том что он парсит первый лист(Sheet1) и не идет на след, также там есть еще пару листов(sheet2, sheet3). Мне нужно их тоже распарсить. Помогите!

```
loc = ("file.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc, encoding_override="iso-8859-5, cyrillic") 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

#print(sheet.row_values(4))

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

# Extracting number of rows 
#print(sheet.nrows) 
dataM = []
data = []

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    if(sheet.row_values(i)[0] != 'test'):
        dataM.append((tuple(sheet.row_values(i))))

for t in dataM:
    #print(t[3])
    data.append((tuple(t)))

for t in data:
    print(t)
```

Comment: Напишите функцию, которая принимает в качестве аргумента объект типа `work_sheet` и которая делает с ним нужные вам манипуляции. Дальше вызывайте эиу функцию для всех листов Excel файла... PS а вообще на Pandas это все делается в несколько строк, но для начала надо понять что же вы хотите получить на выходе. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Я разобрался, не заметил строку, кстати вот она wb.sheet_by_index(0). Спасибо вам за помощь!